# Complementary and orthogonal subspaces

Tags: vector-spaces

Let's consider the vectorial space $\mathbb{R}^m$, a matrix $A$, and two subspaces which are mutually orthogonal and complementary, let's call them $\mathcal{R}(A)$, the range or column space of $A$, and $\mathcal{N}(A^T)$, the null space or kernel of $A^T$.

$$
\mathcal{R}(A) \cap \mathcal{N}(A^T) = \emptyset
$$
$$
\mathcal{R}(A) \cup \mathcal{N}(A^T) = \mathbb{R}^m
$$
$$
dim(\mathcal{R}(A)) + dim(\mathcal{N}(A^T)) = m
$$

I read that a generic vector $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$ can be written as $b = b_R + b_N$ that are the components corresponding to the relative subset.
This is important because in this way we can study methods of approximate resolution of linear systems.

The point I don't get is this: if $\mathcal{R}(A)$ and $\mathcal{N}(A^T)$ are complementary then $b \in \mathcal{R}(A) \lor b \in \mathcal{N}(A^T)$, a generic vector is either in one subset or in the other. Which is the point of writing $b = b_R + b_N$? Moreover since $b_R \in \mathcal{R}(A) \land b_N \in \mathcal{N}(A^T)$ they should have different dimensions, so how can they be summed?

Could you help me understand this topic?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true of complementary subspaces $\mathcal{R}(A)$ and $\mathcal{N}(A^T)$ that every vector is in either one subspace or the other, only that every vector is in the span of the union of the bases of the two subspaces.

For example, let $V,W \in \mathbb{R}^3$ be defined as follows: $V$ is the $x$-axis (the span of $\{(1,0,0)\}$), and $W$ is the $yz$-plane (the span of $\{(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$). These subspaces are complementary, but the vector $(2,1,5)$ does not belong to either subspaces. (It can, however, be written as the sum $(2,0,0) + (0,1,5)$ of vectors in $V$ and $W$.)

This is the only way we can define complementary subspaces. The set-theoretic complement of a subspace is generally not a subspace; if $V$ is a subspace, $v$ is some vector in $V$, and $w$ is some vector not in $V$, then $w$ and $v-w$ will both be in the set-theoretic complement of $V$, but $w + (v-w) = v$ will not be.